# bind9 configuration connection timed out

Tags: networking, dns

I'm trying to make my own nameserver without 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4. I had it set up in the beginning but I don't know where I went wrong, all I get is

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

This is my zone file

```
zone "my-new-place.com" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/my-new-place.com";
};
```

This is my `/etc/resolv.conf` file, I'm using 888 as my eth0 ipv4

```
search my-new-place.com
nameserver 192.168.1.888
```

This is my my nameserver file

```
$TTL 864
@ IN SOA k.my-new-place.com root.my-email.com (
 2
 3600
 900
 604800
 864
)
@ IN NS k.my-new-place.com

k.my-new-place.com IN A 89.31.143.1
```

This is my control file `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```
ACL bindMe {
192.168.1.0/24;
};

options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";
listen-on port 53 { 192.168.1.888; 127.0.0.1; };
allow-query { localhost; bindMe; };
forwarders { 192.168.1.1; };
recursion yes;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what is happening.  I imagine that `bind` is *not* running, due to errors in your configurations, so it is unreachable.  If this isn't helpful, please edit your post to include the command you're running, and additional output.

When you interact with `bind`, are you using `systemctl`?  For example:

```
systemctl restart bind9
```

When you do this, does the command spit out any errors?  Normally when something is wrong, it will direct you to look at `journalctl`.  What is the system telling you is wrong?

You can check if bind is running using `systemctl status bind9`, or `ps aux | grep named`, and possibly `rndc status`.

Maybe you have your `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` correct, but you did not post one, so be sure that you have the zone entries in that file.  You will need one per domain, and one per subnet served:

```
zone "example.tld" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/example.tld.zone";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/192.168.1.zone";
};
```

Here is a working `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`, **however**, I've adjusted the IP to read `.200`, since [`.888` is **not** a valid IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address).

```
    options {
            directory "/var/cache/bind";

            // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
            // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
            // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

            // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
            // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
            // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
            // the all-0's placeholder.

            // forwarders {
            //      0.0.0.0;
            // };

            //========================================================================
            // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
            // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
            //========================================================================
            recursion yes;
            allow-recursion {localnets; 192.168.1.0/16;};

            forwarders {
                    192.168.1.1;
            };

            dnssec-enable yes;
            dnssec-validation auto;
            dnssec-lookaside auto;

            auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
            listen-on { 192.168.1.200; 127.0.0.1; };
            // listen-on-ipv6 { any; };
    };
```

After you've double-checked the settings, restart `bind` and find the logs and output to determine the problem. Please post the exact commands, and logs you've found, as there may be even more wrong and it will be hard for anybody to help without all of the details.

An additional tip would be to change one thing at a time.  Change your IP, verify you still have connectivity.  Then, adjust bind, etc.  Take an iterative approach, and ensure that each time you make a change, you haven't broken everything else.

Comment: +1 for .888 is not a valid IP.

Comment: .888 was just used an example without using my real IPV4 mr.